# Load two json files with same parent key name

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, merge

I have two json files with the same parent key.

Example:
FileA:

```
{ "results": [
    {
        "createdAt": "2014-02-25T23:49:39.076Z",
        "eventAddress": "1342 Worchester Drive Northeast",
        "eventAddress2": "",
        "eventCheckInCount": 600,
        "eventCity": "Atlanta",
        "eventCost": "100.00"
    }
}
```

FileB:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "title": "NIGHT RIOTS",
            "url": "http://www.centerstage-atlanta.com/show?id=1688&artist=NIGHT+RIOTS",
            "date": "3/27/2015 0:00:00",
            "time": "7:00:00 PM"
        },
        {
            "title": "HORSE FEATHERS",
            "url": "http://www.centerstage-atlanta.com/show?id=1641&artist=HORSE+FEATHERS",
            "date": "3/23/2015 0:00:00",
            "time": ""
        }
}
```

Basically I have written a javascript code to merge the keys within the two json outputs, but managed to do so when I gave a variable name to each of them like this.

In FileA:
var filea = { "results" : {[]}}

In FileB:
var fileb = { "results" : {[]}}

However, given the number of files and their size, it is tedious to add the "var filea = " to every json file. In html, if I include a script tag for both the above files, how can I read the data from each file into two different variables.

Is there any other method to merge json files into one, from your experience.

Regards,

Shahid

Comment: why do you need `var` at all? If you load the files with ajax it isn't needed and would actually fail since it would no longer be valid json. Another alternative is read the files at server and decode to arrays and merge there

Comment: Actually, I am not using jQuery at all, it was a tag suggested by stackoverflow. I am trying to avoid server based anything. Right now, I am doing everything offline using a simple .html file

Comment: I get what you are suggesting though, you want me to dynamically load those two files into a separate variable, instead of using <script> tag. I am not sure whether it is supported when the html file is run over a file:// protocol though. I'll check. Can you suggest the code to load using ajax

Comment: no it's not...although you can force it with browser settings. Also could install a local server on your machine if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As charlietfl had commented above, I ended up using XMLHttpRequest and loading each of the json files into seperate variables. XMLHttpRequest fails on Chrome when in file:// protocol, but I got my user to switch to FF, since Chrome had restrictions on other parts of the task as well.

Shahid

```
<input type="text" id="filea" value="" />
<input type="text" id="fileb" value="" />
<input type="button" value="Merge" onclick="mergeJSON();return false" />

<script>
    function getJSON(filename) {
        var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
        req.open('GET', filename, false); 
        req.send(null);
        if(req.status != 200)
            alert('Error reading file: ' + filename);
        return req.responseText;
    }

        fileaname = document.getElementById('filea').value;
        filebname = document.getElementById('fileb').value;

            //our return object
            var ret = getJSON(fileaname);
            var fileb = getJSON(filebname);

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would concatenate both files, remove whitespaces for simplicity, and then use a regular expression to look behind of "results" and capture it.

This is how you would do it from bash, I guess you could do it similar with javascript in case you need it.

```
cat FileA.json FileB.json > concatenated.json
sed -r 's/\s+//g'
cat concatenated.json | grep -oE '"results":{[.*]}'
```

And then use that output for whatever it fits to your needs.

PS: you can test your regular expression in [**here**](http://regexpal.com/).

**EDIT:**

Is there any reason you couldn't just use [**extend**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/) if you are using JQuery?

Comment: One problem with concatenation is that some sub keys from both files can have different values. In such a situation the value in filea needs to take priority over the other.

Comment: But the idea is not to store the concatenated text, it would be just to extract the parts you need from it with the regular expression and then use the output of the regular expression instead. Also, note that concatenation isn't fully necessary, you could perform the regular expression for each one of the files and then perform your logic with each of the outputs. I just mentioned that way because it would be the easiest perform for the simplest case.